# Problem with Visual Studio Code with Python

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code

Someone can help me to solve this problem, i have this error in Vsc:
"The environment variable 'Path' seems to have some paths containing the '"' character. The existence of such a character is known to have caused the Python extension to not load. If the extension fails to load please modify your paths to remove this '"' character."

this is my patch system:
"   %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH;C:\src\flutter\bin;"c:\windows;c:\windows\system32";C:;C:\Users\Admin;C:\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Python\Python310;C:\Python\Python310\Scripts;C:\Users\Admin\Desktop;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;     "

Patch user is:
"        C:;C:\Python\Python310;C:\src\flutter;C:\Users\Admin;C:\Python\Python310\Scripts;C:\Users\Admin\Desktop;C:\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm          "

Comment: Please do not add unrelated tags. That is considered spamming. There is no related to Java or C visible.

Comment: If you look in your PATH string, you'll see in the middle of the list `...bin;"c:\windows;c:\windows\system32";C...` Notice those double quotes, they should not be there. The error message was explicit about that being the problem, so I searched for `"` in your question and found those.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in your system path string, you'll see in the middle of the list

```
...bin;"c:\windows;c:\windows\system32";C...
```

Notice those double quotes, they should not be there. The error message was explicit about that being the problem, so I searched for `"` in your question and found those.

So the solution will be to edit your system path and replace `"c:\windows;c:\windows\system32"` by `c:\windows;c:\windows\system32` without quotes.